# How do you properly write a novel with very little dialogues?

Tags: novel, dialogue

How do you properly write a novel with very little dialogues? I tried doing it and it reads awful. It looks weird if you look at the format and layout if you don't insure the descriptive parts don't exceed 1 or 2 paragraphs. If dialogues are kept at a minimum of 3-5 lines before a descriptive section, it just look plain wrong. How do you manage to do this properly?

Comment: Do you have any novels with little dialogue to use as examples? And what is it about this style choice that appeals to you?

Comment: I watched a movie, Quest for Fire, in which all the actors either grunted or spoke a language no one was meant to understand. They carried it off with gestures, expressions (in writing, these would be show-not-tell descriptions) and actions. Internal dialogue would be important too.

Comment: You could do a letter-style novel, like Stoker's Dracula, but I'm not sure if this works for your project.

Comment: In a movie script you expect much more dialogue than you would in a novel.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the story? WHY is there little dialog? No one to talk to? Everyone speaks a foreign language? The main character is anti-social? A lighthouse  keeper besieged by sea demons? The reasons for this will be critical to understanding how it would need to be carried off. The "Quest for Fire" example I gave is because no one had language (ancient cave dwellers). Tom Hanks in "Cast Away" had no one to talk to because he was alone (but talked to a volley ball).

Comment: I suggest you read either White Fang or Call of the Wild. Yes, there is talking, but there are many segments where there is no talking, and especially on parts thst mainly focus on the protagonists (spoiler: Both protagonists are dogs).